# Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe on call from Provider flutter

Tags: flutter

This issue is weird in that upon fully restarting the app, it works fine until you navigate to the `CreateJoinPage`, then navigate back to the homepage and then navigate forward to `CreateJoinPage` and then try to execute the block of code, the error message will start to pop up. I am creating a listener in `CreateJoinPage` that listens for input from `socket.io`:

```
void createRoomSuccessListener(BuildContext context) {
_socketClient.on('createRoomSuccess', (room2) {
  Provider.of<RoomDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
      .updateRoomData(room);
  Provider.of<RoomDataProvider>(context, listen: false).insertPlayer(room);
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (contextPage) => const ActivitySelectionPage()),
  );
});
```

}

and this error is called from either of the two `Provider.of` lines being part of the code.

This listener is called from my `CreateJoinPage(StatelessWidget)` as such:

```
SocketMethods().createRoomSuccessListener(context);
```

The full error code is:

> Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
> At this point, the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` in the widget's `didChangeDependencies()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the `context` gets destroyed in the meantime a socket event arrives. To fix that the listener should be removed if the `CreateJoinPage` widget is disposed. First, change the `CreateJoinPage` from `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` to override the `disposed` method like so:

```dart
void removeRoomSuccessListener() {
  _socketClient.off('createRoomSuccess');
}


class CreateJoinPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<CreateJoinPage> createState() => _CreateJoinPageState();

  ...
}

class _CreateJoinPageState extends State<CreateJoinPage> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    SocketMethods().removeRoomSuccessListener(context);
    super.dispose();
  }

  ...
}
```

And declare the `SocketMethods.removeRoomSuccessListener` like so:

```dart
void removeRoomSuccessListener() {
  _socketClient.off('createRoomSuccess');
}
```